# Codeigniter Cart: How to add multiple items with ajax and jquery

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, shopping-cart

I'm building a ajax based shopping cart with Codeigniter, and the add / remove functions work perfectly. I am now trying to add an option for adding multiple items, and can't get it to work.

Here's the markup I'm using. I'm not sure if it's the best design, but it's working with the non-ajax function, so I guess it should be fine.

```
<form action="cart/add_multiple" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][id]" value="3571310" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][qty]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][price]" value="59.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][name]" value="London" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][heb_name]" value="לונדון" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][full_price]" value="59.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[0][discount_price]" value="59.00" />

<input type="hidden" name="items[1][id]" value="7397903" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][qty]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][price]" value="29.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][name]" value="London Triple" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][heb_name]" value="לונדון טריפל" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][full_price]" value="29.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="items[1][discount_price]" value="29.00" />
<input type="submit" name="add_multi" value="add to cart"  /></form>
```

The ajax script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("submit", "div#winning_combo_small form", function () { //catches every click on the submit button of the "add to cart" form
    var items = $(this).serialize();

    alert(items);
    $.post(base_url + "cart/add_multiple", {items: items, ajax: '1' },
            function(data){
                if (data =='true')
                    { // Interact with returned data
                        $.get(base_url + "cart", function(cart){ // Get the contents of the url cart/show_cart
                        $("#cart_sidebar").html(cart);
                        })

                        $.get(base_url + "cart/count_items", function(items){
                            $("#cart_items").html(items);
                        })
                    }
                });
  return false;
})
});
```

But it's not working, because the `add_multiple` function receives the data as a string, not an array. Do I have to decode the data somehow to convert it to an array? Do the Hebrew characters get in the way and mess it all up?

I should say that when posting the form the regular way, without ajax, the items are added to the cart and all works well. So what is the difference between the regular post and the ajax post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it to work, though I'm not sure if it's the most elegant way.

Here's what I did:

In the ajax script, I changed `var items = $(this).serialize();` to `var items = $(this).serializeArray();`. I now get an array instead of a string, but it's not the format I need to insert into the cart. So I looped over this array to create an array in the desired format, and used that new array to insert into the cart.

This is my add_multiple function under the cart controller:

```
 function add_multiple()
{
    $items = $this->input->post('items');
    $ajax = $this->input->post('ajax');

    // Check if user has javascript enabled
    if($ajax != '1'){
        $this->cart->insert($items); //if posted the regular non-ajax way, the fields will be in an array in the correct format
        echo 'false';
        redirect('cart'); // If javascript is not enabled, reload the page with new data
    }else{

        $i = 0;
        foreach($items as $key=>$form_field)
        {
            $field_name = $form_field['name'];
            $from_char = strrpos($field_name, '[') +1 ;
            $length = strlen($field_name)-$from_char-1;
            $field = substr($field_name,$from_char,$length);

            $data[$i][$field] = $form_field['value'];
            if ($field == "discount_price") $i+=1; // I know 'discount price' is always the last field
        }

        $this->cart->insert($data);

        echo 'true'; // If javascript is enabled, return true, so the cart gets updated
    }
}
```